# How can I use char *c = "\x0D\x0A" in swift

Tags: swift

I want to write a two bytes char data with "\x0D\x0A".

In objective-c,I can just write `char *c = "\x0D\x0A"`,and I can use `[NSData dataWithBytes:"\x0D\x0A" length:2]` to create a NSData.

Now I want to do with the same way in Swift to create a `Data` with these two bytes or other things.

But there is a error when I used `var c = "\x0D\x0A"`,and if I change it to `var c = "\\x0D\\x0A`,then there will be no error but `c` is a real string with 8 characters.

So how can I fix this?

Comment: Out of interest, what's the error message?

Comment: The compile message is `Invalid escape sequence in literal`

Comment: Since your goal is to create a Data with two bytes, put that in your title and make that the focus of your question.

Comment: According to https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html, you should be able to use `"\r\n"` or `"\u{D}\u{A}"`, but those are Unicode characters, not bytes.

Comment: If I can just create char* in swift like "\x0D\x0A" then I can easy transform it to `Data`,the detail is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C, `char *` can easily convert to byte , so that means `"\x0D"` was just a byte. And in Swift, if you want to use byte, you can also use `Uint8`

So `char *c = "\x0D\x0A"` can be instead of `let c:[Uint8] = [0x0D,0x0A]`, and that's all.

Comment: You said you wanted a `Data` instance with the two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's three ways to create a `Data` instance with the two bytes:

```
let crlfData = Data([ 0x0d, 0x0a])
```

or:

```
let crlfData = "\u{0d}\u{0a}".data(using: .utf8)!
```

or:

```
var crlfData = Data()
crlfData.append(0x0d)
crlfData.append(0x0a)
```